# mapping over list objects and applying a formula

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to apply the following formula to each of my list integers.

```
((TP * TN) - (FP * FN)) / sqrt((TP + FP) * (TP+FN) * (TN+FP) * (TN+FN))
```

I am trying with `pmap` but cannot seem to make the calculation work.

Data:

```
TP <- list(12734L, 12765L, 12842L, 12786L)
FP <- list(262L, 212L, 215L, 198L)
FN <- list(635L, 869L, 943L, 1081L)
TN <- list(869L, 654L, 500L, 435L)
```

I run the following:

```
TP <- list(12734L, 12765L, 12842L, 12786L)
FP <- list(262L, 212L, 215L, 198L)
FN <- list(635L, 869L, 943L, 1081L)
TN <- list(869L, 654L, 500L, 435L)

lst1 <- list(TP, FP, FN, TN)
purrr::pmap(lst1, ~ ((..1 * ..4) - (..2 * ..3))/sqrt((..1 + ..2) * (..1 + ..3) * (..4 + ..2) * (..4 + ..3)))
```

Which outputs:

```
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] NA

[[4]]
[1] NA

Warning messages:
1: In (..1 + ..2) * (..1 + ..3) * (..4 + ..2) :
  NAs produced by integer overflow
2: In (..1 + ..2) * (..1 + ..3) * (..4 + ..2) :
  NAs produced by integer overflow
3: In (..1 + ..2) * (..1 + ..3) * (..4 + ..2) :
  NAs produced by integer overflow
4: In (..1 + ..2) * (..1 + ..3) * (..4 + ..2) :
  NAs produced by integer overflow
```

Comment: Try with `pmap(lst1, ~ ((..1 * ..4) - (..2 * ..3))/sqrt((..1 + ..2) * (..1 + ..3) * (..4  + ..2) * (..4  + ..3)))`

Comment: I get `Warning messages:
1: In (..1 + ..2) * (..1 + ..3) * (..4 + ..2) :
  NAs produced by integer overflow`

Comment: Can you check thee formula used

Comment: I think thee formula showed is not correct `((TP[[1]] * TN[[1]]) - (FP[[1]] * FN[[1]])) / sqrt((TP[[1]] + FP[[1]]) * (TP[[1]]+FN[[1]]) * (TN[[1]]+FP[[1]]) * (TN[[1]]+FN[[1]]))#
[1] NA
Warning message:
In (TP[[1]] + FP[[1]]) * (TP[[1]] + FN[[1]]) * (TN[[1]] + FP[[1]]) :
  NAs produced by integer overflow`

Comment: I added an edit to show exactly what I have done.

Comment: The issue is with the `integer` class. Convert it to `numeric`

Comment: Converting to numeric works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap all the `list` elements in a `list`

```
lst1 <- list(TP, FP, FN, TN)
```

The `list` elements are all integer class and based on the calculation, the values `*` would get really big numbers which exceed the values range for `integer`.  May be it should be converted to big integer class or use `numeric`

```
library(purrr)
pmap_dbl(lst1, ~ ((as.numeric(..1) * as.numeric(..4))  - 
              (as.numeric(..2) * as.numeric(..3)))/
   sqrt((as.numeric(..1) + as.numeric(..2)) * (as.numeric(..1) + 
         as.numeric(..3)) * (as.numeric(..4) + as.numeric(..2)) * 
         (as.numeric(..4) + as.numeric(..3))))
#[1] 0.6340100 0.5344409 0.4563071 0.4068497
```

---

Also, as the `list` are all of equal length, it may be better to convert it to a `vector` and as columns of a data.frame, we can apply the functions much easier

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(TP, FP, FN, TN) %>% 
    unnest(c(TP, FP, FN, TN)) %>%
    mutate_all(as.numeric) %>%
    transmute(out = f1(TP, FP, FN, TN))
# A tibble: 4 x 1
#    out
#  <dbl>
#1 0.634
#2 0.534
#3 0.456
#4 0.407
```

where

```
f1 <- function(TP, FP, FN, TN) {
         ((TP * TN) - (FP * FN)) /
          sqrt((TP + FP) * (TP+FN) * (TN+FP) * (TN+FN))
      }
```